# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have the implementation of Branch and Bound I'am getting error in this function there is priority queue which will used further its getting `IllegalArgumentException`

**//here is that line on which I'am getting this error**

```
 PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(0, comp);

    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.PriorityQueue;

    public class Node {
        private int N = 3;
        Node parent;
        int[][] mat = new int[N][N];
        int x, y;
        int cost;
        int level;

        public void printMatrix(int[][] mat) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(mat[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public void newNode(int[][] mat, int x, int y, int newX, int newY, int level, Node parent) {
            Node node = new Node();
            node.parent = parent;
            node.mat = mat;
            node.mat[x][y] = node.mat[newX][newY];
            node.cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            node.level = level;
            node.x = newX;
            node.y = newY;
        }

        int[] row = {1, 0, -1, 0};
        int[] col = {0, -1, 0, 1};

        public int calculateCost(int[][] initial, int[][] fin) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < fin.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < fin.length; j++) {
                    if(initial[i][j] != fin[i][j])
                        count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        public int isSafe(int x, int y) {
            if ((x >= 0 && x < N) && (y >= 0 && y < N))
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        public void printPath(Node root) {
            if(root == null)
                return;
            printPath(root.parent);
            printMatrix(root.mat);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

**// here I'am getting error in this function there is priority queue which will used further its getting IllegalArgumentException **

```
 public void solve(int[][] initial, int x, int y, int[][] fin) {
            Comparator<Node> comp = new Comparator<Node>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Node lhs, Node rhs) {
                    if((lhs.cost + lhs.level) > (rhs.cost + rhs.level))
                        return 1;
                    return 0;
                }
            };
//here is that line on which im getting this error
            PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(0, comp);
            Node root = new Node();
            root.newNode(initial, x, y, x, y, 0, null);
            root.cost = calculateCost(initial, fin);
            pq.add(root);

            while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
                Node min = pq.peek();
                pq.remove();
                if(min.cost == 0) {
                    printPath(min);
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if(isSafe(min.x + row[i], min.y + col[i]) == 1) {
                        Node child = new Node();
                        child.newNode(min.mat, min.x, min.y, min.x + row[i], min.y + col[i], min.level + 1, min);
                        child.cost = calculateCost(child.mat, fin);
                        pq.add(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] initial =
                {
                    {1, 2, 3},
                    {5, 6, 0},
                    {7, 8, 4}
                };

            int[][] fin =
                {
                    {1, 2, 3},
                    {5, 0, 6},
                    {8, 7, 4}
                };

            int x = 1, y = 2;

            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.solve(initial, x, y, fin);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to post the COMPLETE stack trace and identify the statement in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: //here is that line on which im getting the error

PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<>(0, comp);

Answer (score 6):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-int-java.util.Comparator-) (emphasis is mine):

> `public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`
>
> Creates a `PriorityQueue` with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.
>
> [...]
>
> **Throws:
>   IllegalArgumentException - if initialCapacity is less than 1**

Comment: who downvoted this? this is the correct answer. Thank you RC